# Computed style about auto margin in chrome dev tool is buggy

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

As CSS spec states [here](//www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#blockwidth).

> The following constraints must hold among the used values of the other properties:
>
> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block

And given a test html file

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
}
p {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit adipisci id, sint dolore. Vero eligendi velit, aperiam ipsam ipsa consequatur aut deleniti cum fugit placeat suscipit cupiditate quis obcaecati est.</p>
</div>
```

Open this page in chrome, we'll see the right margin is `100px`. I think it's not correct, right? Or I miss something?
[image: Wrong screenshot]

And then I toggle the `margin-right: auto` in style panel, Chrome shows the correct margin right value `-100px`, I think:
[image: Correct screenshot]

Is this a Chrome bug?

Comment: same screenshot twice?

Comment: It is curious, but does this have any real impact on anything? My guess is that when chrome rendered the page it calculates auto first, 400px width in a 500px container, and you have 100px margin on the right. then the left margin pushes the `p` to the right, and after you, toggle the auto property chrome just plays catchup

Comment: @dippas  one is 100 the other is -100

Comment: still, the `margin-right` is always set to `auto`. and does OP want to `p` to get out of the parent  container?

Comment: @Moak It doesn't impact others on my simple test page. And I tested on IE 11, it shows `-100px` directly. I'm just curious about this behavior, not facing any issue with it. Thanks all!